# Finding the `Min` and `Max` values of a Property of an **Element** in an Array

Tags: arrays, swift

### I am *NOT* looking for the Min/Max of an Element in an Array.

I AM looking to identify the Element by comparing a **property of the element** with the *same property* of **all the other elements** in the array.

I'm sure this is simple with a few built-in array methods (`Min`/`Max`) and specifying a specific `Comparable`/`Equatable` protocols. Arrays have changed a lot in the last 40 years, and I don't know how to accomplish my goal.

### Details/Specifics...

I have an array of structs (`JimGyro`).  ONE property of the structs (`gpsCt`) in the array will have varying ***AND*** duplicate values.  Another property of the structs (`measVal`) in the array will have varying values.

### My Challenge

- I need to gather together all the elements that have the same `gpsCt`

  - Minimum of 1 / Maximum of 100
- Then determine which element of that 1-100 subset has the max value of `measVal`
- Copy that max val of `measVal` to the `subGrpMaxVal` property of the same element.
- Lastly, Copy that element to a new array.

The last two on the list are easy, but I can't quite figure out the nested loops (`for` / `ForEach` / `Do While`) to accomplish this.

### Thank You in Advance for any/all pointers‼️

### Here's my Structure and Sample Array:

```swift
   struct JimGyro {
      var xGyro: Double
      var yGyro: Double
      var zGyro: Double
      var gpsCt: Int
      var measVal: Double
      var subGrpMaxVal: Double
   }

   var theArray = [
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 1, measVal: 2.3, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 1, measVal: 2.4, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 1, measVal: 2.1, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 2, measVal: 1.6, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 2, measVal: 4.7, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 3, measVal: 4.8, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 3, measVal: 9.2, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 3, measVal: 3.4, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
      JimGyro(xGyro: 0.0235, yGyro: 0.0351, zGyro: 0.0495, gpsCt: 3, measVal: 2.3, subGrpMaxVal: 0),
   ]
```

- GPS Coordinates are read at the rate of **1-*ish* per second**.
- Gyro data is read at the rate of **30-*ish* per second**.

  - (The "ish" is because, due to various reasons, there are not exactly 30 gyro readings for every one GPS reading.)
  - Therefore I ***cannot*** just grab the elements by chunks of 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to gather together all the elements that have the same gpsCt

That is a Dictionary, by grouping:

```
let byCount = Dictionary(grouping: theArray, by: \.gpsCt)
```

Given how you've described it, it isn't quite clear which elements are supposed to update `subGrpMaxVal`, but if the goal is to collect all the maximums in a list, and assign `subGrpMaxVal` to just those, a straightforward way to do that is with a loop:

```
var results: [JimGyro] = []
for group in byCount.values {
    // Find the maximum element (if any)
    if var maxElement = group.max(by: { $0.measVal < $1.measVal }) {
        // Update its subGrpMaxVal
        maxElement.subGrpMaxVal = maxElement.measVal

        // And return it
        results.append(maxElement)
    }
}

print(results)
```

If you want to smash it all together into a FP-chain, it would look like this:

```
let results = Dictionary(grouping: theArray, by: \.gpsCt)
    .values
    .compactMap { group in
        group.max(by: { $0.measVal < $1.measVal }).map {
            var maxElement = $0
            maxElement.subGrpMaxVal = maxElement.measVal
            return maxElement
        }
    }
```

(But I'd probably use the loop...)

Comment: Thank You Rob‼️ You did in 6 lines what it took all day to do unsuccessfully. LOL. I now have a real-world case for learning more about dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a dictionary to store all the groups based on gpsCt

```
var groups: [Int: [JimGyro]] = [:]

for gyro in theArray{
    if groups[gyro.gpsCt] == nil {
        groups[gyro.gpsCt] = [gyro]
    } 
    else{
        groups[gyro.gpsCt]?.append(gyro)
    }
}
```

Now, you need to iterate over groups to find max measVal and update subGrpMaxVal and store it in newArray

```
var newArray = theArray

for (_, group) in groups {
    if let maxGyro = group.max(by: { $0.measVal < $1.measVal }) {
        for index in group.indices {
            newArray[newArray.firstIndex(where: { $0 == group[index] })!].subGrpMaxVal = maxGyro.measVal
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to update your original array, then remove the 'newArray' replace 'newArray' with 'theArray' in code.